# Show pop up on each table row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want show a popup when I click the text "lihat" on the table row. The code I use is this:

```
<?php   
$no=1;
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td align='center'>" .$no. "</td>";
    echo"<td align='center'>" .$result[create_time]. "</td>";
    echo"<td align='center'>" .$result[mesin]. "</td>"; 
    echo"<td align='center'>" .$result[part]. "</td>";
    echo"<td align='center'>" .$result[indikasi]. "</td>"; 
    echo"<td align='center'>" .$result[pelapor]. "</td>"; 
        if($result[status]=='BELUM DIKERJAKAN'){
            echo'<td style="background-color:#ff0000; color:#ffffff" align="center">'.TUNGGU.'</td>';}      
        elseif($result[status]=='DIKERJAKAN'){
            echo'<td style="background-color:#003cd4; color:#ffffff" align="center">'.DIKERJAKAN.'</td>';}
        elseif($result[status]=='TUNDA'){
            echo'<td style="background-color:#ffea00; color:#00000" align="center">'.DITUNDA.'</td>';}
        else{
            echo'<td style="background-color:#06ff00; color:#00000" align="center">'.SELESAI.'</td>';}
    echo"<td align='center'><a class='update' href='#' value='Popup' onclick='window.open(\pltd-siantan/home_wo.php?cat=wo&page=rincian_wo&order_id={$result['order_id']}\',) >Lihat</a></td>";            
    echo"</tr>";
$no++;
}
```

Any solution?

Comment: What you have tried to achieve it??

Comment: This is my code echo"<td align='center'><a class='update' href='#' value='Popup' onclick='window.open(\pltd-siantan/home_wo.php?cat=wo&page=rincian_wo&order_id={$result['order_id']}\',) >Lihat</a></td>";

Comment: For what purpose you need popup?? Do you want to show data from specified url in your popup??

Comment: I want to show data table from that url

Answer (score 0):

The general solution would be to use ajax to send a request ( either get or post ) to your `pltd-siantan/home_wo.php` page and the callback assigned to the ajax function would then display the popup. You can get many different javascript routines to create the popup, probably the best known is Lightbox which you can find [here](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: Thank you for your solution, brother. But I think it can't solve my problem

Comment: What will not solve your problem? The lightbox code or the entire process of generating and rendering the content within a popup? Your code should open a new window / tab but the url begins with a backslash ( \\ ) and it should be a forwardslash ( / ) - does the popup display the data you want?